# Two Dimensional Arrays with User Input

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm making a crossword puzzle grid in which the user enters first the dimensions of the grid then each line separated by a space or enter. The program takes in each line and puts each letter of the line in a spot on the grid[][]. So far I've only managed to make my grid work for a dimension 4x4 or smaller, if I make it any bigger any letter found in grid[0][i] just spits out garbage. If I printf the grid after each iteration of the loop its correct, but if I go back and check its not. Anyone got any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

    int i, j, row, column;

    scanf("%i", &row);
    scanf("%i", &column);

    char *userInput = malloc (sizeof(char)*column);
    char **grid = malloc(sizeof(char)*column);

    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        scanf("%s", userInput);
        grid[i] = (char*) malloc (row *sizeof(char));
        for (j=0; j<column; j++){
            grid[i][j] = userInput[j];
        }
    }

    // double check to see if the grid is correct.
    printf("%c", grid[0][2]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tagged your question as `C`- because it is written in pure C - but maybe consider also C++?

Comment: malloc (sizeof(char)*column); is not enough to hold a string of 'column' characters, you need one more for 0-terminator.
Also, your scanf my very well run out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing indices

- you allocate `column` amount of `char*` pointers
- then you iterate on `row` (when it should be `column`) and allocate a `row` amount of `char` for each index
- then you fill that `char[row]` with a string which has `column` length instead that `row`

Since you are reading `column` characters I assume you want a row x column matrix, what you should do is something like

```
int i, j, row, columnM
char** grid = malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
char* userInput = malloc(column);

for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
  grid[i] = malloc(column);
  ..
  memcpy(grid[i], userInput, column);
}
```

Actually you don't need `sizeof(char)` in allocations since a char is guaranteed to be 1 byte by the standard.

Mind that `scanf` will write a nul terminator at the end of the string read regardless the size of the buffer. So you should provide at least `column+1` bytes to read to. This won't prevent the user from entering more characters and cause a buffer overflow, check my comment.

Comment: I did not use `scanf`for years - but maybe it should be `column + 1` for userInput? I mean - null character at the end...

Comment: Indeed `scanf` is unsafe and should not be used, no matter if you take care of the required nul character because it will write out of bounds. I would just not use it. A solution would be to do something like `scanf("%8s", userInput)` to limit the amount of characters and then have `column = 8 + 1;`.

Comment: `char** grid = malloc(row);` --> `char** grid = malloc(row*sizeof(*grid));`

Comment: I still get garbage when I run the code as a 5x5 grid :/

Comment: nvm I got it %8 did the trick. Someone mind explaining what that does to me? My grid has to hold up to 300x300 would that be able to hold it too?

Answer (score 0):

Your grid malloc is incorrect. It should be

```
char **grid = malloc(sizeof(char*)*column);
```

Grid is an array of "pointer to char" not "char". Seeing garbage is the classic symptom of a buffer overrun (or in this case, buffer under-allocation).

Also, while not *strictly* necessary if you are careful, all character buffers should be allocated with an extra byte for the string terminator (zero).